# Can I upload my play store apk file to other android stores?

Tags: android, app-store, google-play, amazon-appstore

I successfully upload my first Free App on Play Store now I have a very basic question. Can I upload my play store **apk file** to **other android stores** as well? e.g.

1. Play Store (Android Market)
2. Amazon App Store
3. Opera Mobile App Store
4. AndAppStore
5. GetJar
6. Handango OnlyAndroid Superstore by Mobihand
7. Insyde Market
8. Appoke
9. SlideME YAAM Market

Is there is any **restriction or objeaction** from **Play Store** or any other Store on uploading the **same sign App apk** on there store?
If there is any restriction then what should I need to do?

Answer (score 5):

Each market might has it's own restriction. You must read and research each one of them. I can tell you for example that "Amazon's AppStore" will review your app and won't approve it if it has some links for Google play market or other competitiors (Barnes & Nobel). Also, you can't use Google services (such as maps, or in-app billing) in an Amazon android device, so you should know it's another limitation.
As mentioned - you must research every market. Good luck!

Comment: Good answer. I had used appirater in my app. It pointed to the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

**As Officially** said by site here at [Distributing Apps outside Google Play](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/142471?hl=en&ref_topic=2364761)

> Distributing your apps through Google Play is non-exclusive; you may
>   choose to distribute your applications through other channels as well.
>   Keep in mind the version published in the store must comply with all
>   Google Play policies.

Also you Can Read [Policy of Google Play](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/topic/2364761?hl=en&ref_topic=2365624) for Brief and Very well Documented Lines.

Hope it will clear your view about your Problem.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such a clause when you upload your app to the Play Store.But you must only upload to reliable and trustworthee markets. Your apk file may be leaked.

Comment: Uploading your app to the official store is enough to have it leaked... apk mirror sites use dummy Google accounts to harvest apks from the Play Store.